# The specified project directory ''" does not exist

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Ever since I have upgraded my Android Studio 3.0.1 to 3.1 I am not able to run the project.

```
    Executing task 'assemble'..    
            FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
            * What went wrong:
            The specified project directory '' does not exist.
    * Try:
        Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
        BUILD FAILED in 0s
        The specified project directory '' does not exist.
        15:52:35: Task execution finished 'assemble'.
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you are using IntelliJ with Gradle, you may need to unlink a non-existent module in the Gradle tab.

Comment: I assumed IntelliJ would do that automatically when I deleted the module :/

Comment: Man. You deserve a medal!

Answer (score 14):

The issue might also be caused by an empty 'Gradle project:' field under:

```
'Run'
  -> 'Edit Configurations...'
  -> 'Gradle'
  -> 'NAME OF YOUR CONFIGURATION'
  -> 'Configuration'
  -> 'Gradle project:'
```

Filling out this field by selecting the root directory of my application (an clicking on 'Apply') resolved the issue for me.

[image]

Comment: When you say "Gradle", are you refering to the tab under "Defaults"?

Comment: I edited the answer and added a picture. You can see I referred to the main tab "Gradle" above the "Defaults" tab.

Answer (score 7):

Delete .idea and .gradle folders and try to re-import the project. I had refactored my project name and I ran into the issue and deleting .idea and .gradle folders and re importing worked as it clears the meta data of project configuration for intellij or android studio.

Answer (score 5):

Navigate to "File" and select "Invalidate Caches and Restart" from the drop down. After Android Studio restarts, your project should run.

Answer (score 0):

have same issue
I copy an already existing project and try to run it and got this error

I fix it by

1. Enter to the **settings.gradle** file and change the  "`rootProject.name`" to my new project name

If this not the issue than
2) from left side press on Gradle

[image]

press on project that failed to build and remove it

[image]

[image]

maybe you will need to restart the intelij after